# inner html inside the forloop is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, innerhtml

```
var draftloc = { ans: ["a", "b", "c"] };
for (var i = 0; i < draftloc.ans["length"]; i++) {
  //draftloc.length === draftloc["length"]

  console.log("draftloc for loop works");

  //rcnounk is a element(div)
  rcnounk.innerHTML += `<div class="ml-negative-20 mt-9">
                        <div class="ui check checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="example">
                            <label>${draftloc.ans[i]}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
}
```

for loop is working everything is defined but inner html not working

Comment: "not working". What happens, what doesn't happen, do you get an error..?

Comment: Define "not working".  Perhaps you could turn this into a complete and runnable exampe demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Where and how do you access to the 'rcnounk' Element?

Comment: `draftloc.ans["length"]`? Are you thinking of `draftloc.ans.length`? (It works, but it's a very odd way to write it, you wouldn't normally use the `[""]` notation for built-in properties)

Comment: @David I think, it means that their template string isn't being added to the DOM

Comment: @k0o: I would have thought so too, except that the code [demonstrably works](https://jsfiddle.net/ndL6ybo3/).

Comment: @David that's why I asked how he/she is trying to access the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the DIV-elem from rcnounk.

```
rcnounk=document.getElementById('rcnounk');
```

With this it seems to work.

```js
var draftloc = { ans: ["a", "b", "c"] };
for (var i = 0; i < draftloc.ans["length"]; i++) {
  //draftloc.length === draftloc["length"]

  console.log("draftloc for loop works");

rcnounk=document.getElementById('rcnounk');
  //rcnounk is a element(div)
  rcnounk.innerHTML += `<div class="ml-negative-20 mt-9">
                        <div class="ui check checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="example">
                            <label>${draftloc.ans[i]}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
}
```

```html
<div id='rcnounk'>RC</div>
```